# How to stop this jquery marquee scrolling on mouse over

Tags: jquery, html, css, marquee

I have used the following jquery marquee, but it couldn't stop on mouse over.. is any solution in jquery......

```js
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.marquee').marquee({
    //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
    duration: 10000,
    //gap in pixels between the tickers
    gap: 100,
    //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    //'left' or 'right'
    direction: 'left',
    //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
    duplicated: true
});
</script>
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

Comment: simply remove the class "marquee" from the div tag

Comment: how can i remove the class on mouse over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".marquee").on("mouseover", function(e){
    $(this).marquee("toggle");
});
```

use the "toggle" method to pause and resume the animation.

Comment: Thanks.. class removed but scrolling couldn't stop.. :(

Comment: I have updated the ans to use toggle. give this a try

Comment: you are welcome, please accept the answer if possible =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option pauseOnHover. See: https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee/blob/master/README.md